# How to get the ECS instance id tp specify in the cloud formation template?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-auto-scaling

I am building a cloud formation template(YML format) for my ECS service and stuck in load-balancer target group, it was not able to attach to my ECS instance and trying to add `Targets` by referring this official AWS docs https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-elasticloadbalancingv2-targetgroup-targetdescription.html

**Below is my target group and as I stop start(which terminates) my instance several times, my instance id will be changing all the time and will not be static, like VPC or subnet ids and how can I build the value dynamically in Id field of Targets ?**

```
TargetGroup:
    Type: AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::TargetGroup
    Properties: 
      Matcher: 
       HttpCode: "200"
      Name: "foo"
      Port: "8080"
      Protocol: "HTTP"
      Targets:
        Id: String // This I need to build dynamically
        Port: 8080
      TargetType: "instance"
      UnhealthyThresholdCount: 3
      VpcId: "vpc-79251d11"
```

Note: I tried search for EC2 resources and found this https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/quickref-ec2.html but it didn't help me. **Also I am using ASG and LC to create my ECS instance.**

Comment: Why would instance id change? Its not like a public IP address when it changes each time you restart the instance.

Comment: @Marcin thanks for your comment, I am stopping instance everyday using ASG and want to build this cloud formation generic, lets suppose if I use it for another service or even want to use for another AWS account, having a hardcode value wont create issue in that?

Comment: If an instance is created by your CFN template, then you are not hardcoding it. You will just reference it using `!Ref`. If you deploy your template in the other account it will still work, because you are referencing instance here, not hard coding its id.

Comment: @Marcin and I just checked by stopping the instance using ASG and then again starting it, it changed the instance id

Comment: I think we are taking about different IDs. Can you provide an example?

Comment: @Marcin, it looks like `i-07fbdd511c57f06a3` and I guess this is what I need to provide in targets of target group?

Comment: That's correct, and it does not change when you stop an instance. Maybe you are talking about terminating it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214475/discussion-between-es-enthu-and-marcin).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the discussion in chat.

Since the instances will be running in an **Auto Scaling Group**, there is no need to specify their ids directly in the `TargetGroup` resource of type  `AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::TargetGroup`.

Instead `TargetGroup` ARN should be provided in the `AWS::AutoScaling::AutoScalingGroup` resource. Specifically, [TargetGroupARNs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-as-group.html#cfn-as-group-targetgrouparns) parameter:

> A list of Amazon Resource Names (ARN) of target groups to associate with the Auto Scaling group. Instances are registered as targets in a target group, and traffic is routed to the target group.

For example, since your `AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::TargetGroup` resource is called `TargetGroup`, when defining your ASG you would do the following (if same template file):

```
MyASG:
    Type: AWS::AutoScaling::AutoScalingGroup
    Properties: 
      # only one parameter shown
      TargetGroupARNs: 
        - !Ref TargetGroup
```

Naturally, you would skip `Targets` parameter in your `TargetGroup`. This will make `MyASG` automatically register/de-register your instances from the `TargetGroup`.

Comment: Is there a way to this if my ASG already exists, and I am creating LB later as per requirement? I can do this from CLI, but unable to find a was from CF. Additionally, my ASG was not created using CF.